# Mapping Fluent NHibernate where the primary key should also be a foreign key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a user object like so:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

this is fluently mapped in nhibernate:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UserId).Column("UserId");
        Map(x => x.UserName).Not.Nullable();
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm trying to build a credential block that is separate from the user object, so the password and salt are not carried around in the user class like so:

```
public class UserCredential
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public byte[] Password { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
}
```

...but I cannot figure out how to properly map this.  Ultimately, in the database, I would expect to see a `UserId` column in the `UserCredentials` table, that is both a primary key and a foreign key to the `Users` table.  The `Users` table should have no reference to the `UserCredentials` table.  How would I write that `ClassMap<UserCredential>` class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a `one-to-one` relationship and would therefore be mapped using `HasOne` in FNH.

#### Example

```
    public UserCredentialMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("UserId")
            .GeneratedBy.Foreign("User");

        HasOne(x => x.User).Constrained();
    }
```

You may be able to map it like this as well:

```
public UserCredentialMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id, "UserId");

    References(x => x.User, "UserId")
            .Not.Update()
            .Not.Insert();
}
```

Comment: Could you please expand on this?  How would I write the class map for this?  Does HasOne() replace the Id()?  How do I specify the UserId is the primary and foreign key?

Comment: I've provided an example of this above.

Comment: OK, thanks... the `Id` property you're specifying, is that supposed to be  the `User` property or are you implying that I need to create a new property in my class for this?

Comment: I'm implying that you would have an Id property in `UserCredential` yes.  Also look at my alternative mapping.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't want to give the `Credentials` it's own primary key, it seems to me that what you really want is a [Component](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#Components) ([more details](http://fluentnhibernate.org/blog/2010/05/23/feature-focus-componentmap.html)).

This will mean that the `Credential` data is stored in the same table as the `User` data, but is modelled in your domain as a separate object which is a property of your User class.

Comment: That... sounds very interesting!  I will see if I can figure out how to make this work.

Comment: I think this is not going to work for what I want; I do not want the credential information accessible from the `User` object externally... I want the relationship managed solely in the Credential object.  Can I do that with a Component?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense, at least to me, why would a `Credential` object **own** a `User` and not the other way round?

Comment: Ownership... is probably not the right word.  It's an access thing.  I want to manage the password and salt in the class library and pass around a user object that does not contain authentication information in it.  My membership provider will be the only thing accessing the Credential class (I will probably make it internal).  Does that make sense?

Comment: Then they are separate objects and need their own primary keys resulting in a simple one-to-one mapping as Cole said.

Comment: Well, I expected that.  But I don't have a good understanding of the `HasOne()` mapping, and I cannot wrap my brain around how I would write that as a primary key and a foreign key for the same column.

Comment: Why is it essential that they share the same Id?  This feels misguided and unnecessary with a high chance for complications and confusion later.

Comment: A credential object will reference exactly one user.  In database design this is a common practice for such situations, as it doesn't make sense to create another column when your foreign key is uniquely constrained.  You'll see this a lot in inheritance models too.

Comment: I faced a similar situation, with the same concern that you had with the sharing of th Id. What I found out, that with @Cole suggested mapping, you'll get constrained foreign key, with no need to bidirecting the relationship. The only thing, as you said, that you should specify the Id field (in POCO), because otherwise you won't have an Id for this class.